# React form hook - validation, no Trailing or Leading or only white spaces for input value

Tags: validation, react-typescript

I'm trying to create a validator in "react-hook-form": "^7.3.6" @typescript with @material-ui for cases that includes whitespace in the input field; for example, a user can enter "     "/"  username"/"  username   "   and it will be a valid username.

I have tried several Regular expressions in the `pattern` field but didn't come up with the right one for what I'm looking for, or am I not approaching this the right way?

```jsx
<TextField
    variant="outlined"
    margin="normal"
    required
    fullWidth
    id="username"
    label="Enter Username"
    name="username"
    autoFocus
    {...register("username",  {
        required: "required",
        minLength: {
            value: 3,
            message: "minimum number of character for username is 3"
        },
        pattern: {
            value: /\s/g,
            message: "Entered value cant start/end or contain only white spacing"
            },
        })}
        helperText={errors.username?.message}
    />
```

Comment: `\s` will match any space anywhere in the input, which I'm guessing isn't what you want, based on the `message` parameter.

Comment: Your question title and body ask for two different things: is " username " valid or invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `/^[^\s]+(?:$|.*[^\s]+$)/` for your regular expression, if you are trying to match valid inputs (`/(?:^\s+|\s+$)/` will match the opposite, invalid inputs). `/\s/g` will catch any string that contains whitespace (e.g. match: `"this string matches"`, no match: `"this_string_doesn't"`).

Comment: Hi, conner thank you for the response. I entered this RegEx to the PATTERN, the result was that "username" only accepts values that contain white space, which is the opposite of what I'm looking to achieve...for example (email validator):    pattern: {
                      value: /\S+@\S+.\S+/,
                      message: "Entered value does not match email format"
                    }

Comment: From your question code (`value: /\s/g`), it looked like you wanted a regex that matched an incorrect input. I'll update my answer with the opposite.